# How to iterate through a datatable and set values?

Tags: c#

How would I go about doing something similar to the code below? I'd like to iterate through my datatable and set / change values. In this case, setting all of the rows DateRcvd to the current date.

```
foreach(DataRow row in SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl.Rows)
{
    row.Field<DateTime>("DateRcvd") = DateTime.Today;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modern way of writing it is:

```
row.SetField("DateRcvd", DateTime.Today);
```

Since `SetField` is a generic method, it won't box your value type like using the default indexer will (the indexer takes an `object`).

Comment: can you explain quickly why this is a better solution to the one below?

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through each row and use an indexer property of the `DataRow`:

```
foreach(DataRow row in SubVwr.Tables[0].Tbl.Rows)
{
   row["DateRcvd"] = DateTime.Today;
}
```